# User relashionship in a order

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am having an issue in setting up a one to many relationship, I have a class user, user has roles and I making order class so order has two users(employer and customer) and I got error on mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: br.com.meusite.models.Order.user in br.com.meusite.models.User.orders.

I have the following - this is the `User` class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String username;

@JsonIgnore
@NotEmpty
private String password;

@Email
private String email;

private BigDecimal balance;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="TELEFONE")
private Set<String> telefones = new HashSet<>();

@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name="ROLES")
private Set<Integer> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

then this is the `Order` class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User customer;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User employer;

private Payment payment;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.order")
private Set<ItemOrder> items = new HashSet<>();

@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime date;
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `User` file, the `mappedBy` attribute is referencing `user` while the property on `Order` file is `employer`, that's the error. So either change your mapping into:

```
// on User
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
// on Order
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User user;
```

**Note:** and also, please check for duplicate variables

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User customer;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   private User employer;
```

Comment: I want to know who was the employee and the customer who placed the order, for this duplicated variables

Comment: Why not just create a query to do that for you?

Comment: yap, like @Chi-YoungJeffreyLii said, if it's on same table, use query for that, unless if it's on different tables (different entities), you have to update it too

Comment: Also if you have the ability to edit the table schema it might be better to just create a view and access that directly if it's a time critical thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to tell hibernate to create a relationship from user to order referencing the `user` field in the order entity. You should be using the foreign key in the user table. You must change

```
    @OneToMany(name = "user")
```

to

```
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "whatever_the_foreign_key_is.")
```

Please show a screenshot of the order and user table for further assistance.